# How to apply common test configuration to all projects?

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm migrating an old project to Scala 3. The `build.sbt` is as follows:

```
import Dependencies._

inThisBuild(
  Seq(
    scalaVersion := "2.12.7",
    scalacOptions ++= Seq(
      "-unchecked",
      // more
    )
  )
    ++ inConfig(Test)(Seq(
    testOptions += Tests.Argument(TestFrameworks.ScalaTest, "-o", "-e"),
    // more
  ))
)

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .aggregate(
    `test-util`
  )

lazy val `test-util` = project
```

Now, I want to separate stuff inside `inThisBuild` for legibility.

```
import Dependencies._

ThisBuild / scalaVersion := "3.0.1"
ThisBuild / scalacOptions ++= Seq(
  "-unchecked",
  // more
)

lazy val testSettings = inConfig(Test)(
  Seq(
    testOptions += Tests.Argument(TestFrameworks.ScalaTest, "-o", "-e"),
    // more
  ))


lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .aggregate(
    `test-util`
  )
  .settings(testSettings)

lazy val `test-util` = project
```

As you can see, I'm having to apply the `testSettings` for each project. Ideally, I'd like to do something like `ThisBuild / Test := testSettings` but that is not valid syntax.

Is there a way to apply the `testSettings` to all projects without having to explicitly set `.settings(testSettings)`?

*Edit*:

I understand I can write each line of `testSettings` with `ThisBuild / Test` prefix, but I’d rather not repeat the same prefix. I’m looking for something like what I’ve done with `scalacOptions`.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to apply the testSettings to all projects without having to explicitly set `.settings(testSettings)`

Consider creating an auto plugin which can inject settings automatically in all the sub-projects, for example in `project/CommonTestSettings.scala`

```
import sbt._
import Keys._

object CommonTestSettings extends sbt.AutoPlugin {
  override def requires = plugins.JvmPlugin
  override def trigger = allRequirements
  override lazy val projectSettings =
    inConfig(Test)(
      Seq(
        testOptions += Tests.Argument(TestFrameworks.ScalaTest, "-o", "-e")
        // more
      )
    )
}
```

You can test with `show testOptions` which should reveal the common settings in all the sub-projects, for example in my project where `root` aggregates `foo` and `bar` I get something like

```
sbt:sbt-multi-project> show testOptions
[info] foo / Test / testOptions
[info]  List(Argument(Some(TestFramework(org.scalatest.tools.Framework, org.scalatest.tools.ScalaTestFramework)),List(-o, -e)))
[info] bar / Test / testOptions
[info]  List(Argument(Some(TestFramework(org.scalatest.tools.Framework, org.scalatest.tools.ScalaTestFramework)),List(-o, -e)))
[info] Test / testOptions
[info]  List(Argument(Some(TestFramework(org.scalatest.tools.Framework, org.scalatest.tools.ScalaTestFramework)),List(-o, -e)))
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can done with `scalaVersion` and `scalacOptions`, you can do with `Test`. For example:

```
lazy val testSettings = inConfig(Test)(
  Seq(
    testOptions += Tests.Argument(TestFrameworks.ScalaTest, "-o", "-e"),
    // more
  ))
```

Can be rewritten as:

```
ThisBuild / Test / testOptions += Test.Argument(TestFrameworks.ScalaTest, "-o", "-e")
```

Is it this that you want? Or do you want to pass a sequence directly?

Comment: There’s more than just `testOptions` (as shown), I’d like to not repeat `ThisBuild / Test` prefix for each one. I’m looking for something like what I’ve done with `scalacOptions`.